# showing video through apache 5.5

Tags: flash, apache, tomcat, video

I have a problem while showing .flv video file through apache 5.5 server.
I am using jsp2.0 & javascript, flash video player in html.
Whenever i am trying to run the video.jsp page which contains 10mb .flv video file through apache 5.5 server, my c drive is getting full. It also does not show the video on page & my whole laptop is becomming slow.
Please reply me urgently because my project work is stopped.

Comment: You may want to re-title this with tomcat.  The organization is apache.  Apache as a product from the organization generally refers to the apache httpd project.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have set the mime type correctly for FLV:

This should be in your httpd.conf

```
AddType video/x-flv flv
```

You might also need to make sure that the FLV is not being gzipped, something like this:

```
<Location />

# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|flv)$ no-gzip dont-vary

</Location>
```

Hope that helps...

mike